# Game Maker Password Verifier

Tags: loops, input, passwords, alert, gml

How Do I make one flag that checks if:

is_valid_length, is_valid_letters, is_valid_digits, is_valid_at
are all true? also How Do I make it only Display correct at the end and not you must follow the rules at the end. if i take put "output_msg ="You must follow these rules";" then output_msg becomes an unknown variable. Someone help me please and thankyou

```
   {
   var is_valid_length, is_valid_letters, is_valid_digits, is_valid_at, output_msg;
   is_valid_length = false;
   is_valid_letters = false;
   is_valid_digits = false;
   is_valid_at = false;
   var user;
   var length,char;
   length = 0;  
   char = 0;

    do{
   output_msg ="You must follow these rules";
   user=get_string("Enter password:","")
   if (string_length(user)>=6 && string_length(user)<=10){
   is_valid_length = true;
   }
   else{
   output_msg =("Password is not 5-10 characters long");
   }


   if (string_length(string_digits(user))>=1){
   is_valid_digits = true;
   }
   else{
   output_msg +=("#Password Does not contain 1 digit");
   }



   if (string_length(string_letters(user))>=1){
   is_valid_letters = true;
   }
   else{
   output_msg +=("#Password Does not contain 1 letter");
   }



   if (string_count('@',user)>=1){
   is_valid_at=true;
   }
   else{
   output_msg +=("#Password Does not contain @");
   }

   show_message(output_msg);

   if (is_valid_length && is_valid_letters && is_valid_digits && is_valid_at ==true) {
   show_message("correct");

   }
   }

   until 
   is_valid_length = true;
   is_valid_letters = true;
   is_valid_digits = true;
   is_valid_at = true;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can answer part of your question. To make one expression to evaluate all of your boolean you would do:

```
if (is_valid_length && is_valid_letters){
    if (is_valid_digits && is_valid_at){
       show_message("correct");
    }
}
```

I don't think game maker allows for more than one && or ||. You do not need the == true part because just typing them in will evaluate them. If you did something like:

```
if (!is_valid_length){}
```

The ! symbol is evaluating to see if it is NOT true.

As for your second question, the reason output_msg is an unknown variable is because you were deleting the declaration of output_msg.

to make it only display "correct" put an else on the end of your 4 boolean checks like this:

```
if (is_valid_length && is_valid_letters){
    if (is_valid_digits && is_valid_at){
       show_message("correct");
    }
}
else show_message(output_msg);
```

I would do the whole block like this:

```
 var output_msg;
 var is_valid_length = false;
 var is_valid_letters = false;
 var is_valid_digits = false;
 var is_valid_at = false;
 var all_true = false; //variable for all true
 var user;
 var length,char;
 length = 0;  
 char = 0;

 do{
 output_msg ="You must follow these rules";
 user=get_string("Enter password:","")
 if (string_length(user)>=6 && string_length(user)<=10){
 is_valid_length = true;
 }
 else{
 output_msg +=("#Password is not 5-10 characters long");
 is_valid_length = false; //resetting if they get it wrong second try
 }


 if (string_length(string_digits(user))>=1){
 is_valid_digits = true;
 }
 else{
 output_msg +=("#Password Does not contain 1 digit");
 is_valid_digits = false;
 }



 if (string_length(string_letters(user))>=1){
 is_valid_letters = true;
 }
 else{
 output_msg +=("#Password Does not contain 1 letter");
 is_valid_letters = false;
 }



 if (string_count('@',user)>=1){
 is_valid_at=true;
 }
 else{
 output_msg +=("#Password Does not contain @");
 is_valid_at=false;
 }

 if (is_valid_length && is_valid_letters){
     if (is_valid_digits && is_valid_at){
        show_message("correct");
        all_true = true; //exits out of do loop
     }
 }
 else {
     show_message(output_msg);
     all_true = false;

 }
 }
 until all_true == true;
```

Hope this helps